# .Net api and Angular Project "Out of memory." Error

Tags: c#, .net, angular

I'm trying to create pdf in my current project, but unfortunately "Out of memory." I get an error. What is the reason of this?

Below I have shared the .Net code I used to create pdf with you. This code works fine locally, but as I said, it gives an error when it is uploaded to the server.

Note: It gives this error when running on the server, not when running locally.

```
      try
            {
                // SERTİFİKA OLUŞTUR
                string sertifikaId = "0";
                string dosyaadi = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
                string SertifikaAdSoyad = student.FullName.ToString().ToUpper();
                string SertifikaDogumTarihiveYeri = student.BirthDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + " / " + student.BirthPlace.ToString();
                string SertifikaTckn = student.TCKN;
                string SertifikaOlusturan = certificate.Giver;


                PointF firstLocation = new PointF(1290, 257);
                PointF secondLocation = new PointF(1740, 257);
                PrivateFontCollection pfcoll = new PrivateFontCollection();
                pfcoll.AddFontFile($"{Core.Constants.FileResources.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\fonts\\North Type - NTF-Grand Medium Italic.otf");
                System.Drawing.FontFamily ff = pfcoll.Families[0];
                System.Drawing.Color myColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(209, 31, 58);
                SolidBrush KirmiziBrush = new SolidBrush(myColor);
                System.Drawing.Color myColor2 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(88, 88, 90);
                SolidBrush GriBrush = new SolidBrush(myColor2);
                QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
                QRCodeData qrCodedata = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("https://akademi.tbf.org.tr/SertifikaDogrulama.aspx", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
                QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodedata);
                Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(10);
                Font arialFont = new Font(ff, 20, FontStyle.Italic);

                System.Drawing.Image imgBackground = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(certificate.FrontCover);
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgBackground))
                {
                    using (Font ozelFont = new Font(ff, 18, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic))
                    {
                        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(1200, 1690, 1250, 90); // y 40 arttırıldı

                        StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
                        stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                        stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                        graphics.DrawString(SertifikaAdSoyad, new Font(ff, 22, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic), GriBrush, rect1, stringFormat);
                        //graphics.FillRectangle(GriBrush, rect1);
                    }
                }

                Font kucukFont = new Font(ff, 20, FontStyle.Regular);

                System.Drawing.Image imgBackground2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(certificate.BackCover);
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgBackground2))
                {
                    using (Font ozelFont = new Font(ff, 18, FontStyle.Italic))
                    {
                        graphics.DrawString(SertifikaAdSoyad, ozelFont, GriBrush, new Point(1030, 320));
                        graphics.DrawString(SertifikaDogumTarihiveYeri, ozelFont, GriBrush, new Point(1030, 400));
                        graphics.DrawString(SertifikaTckn, ozelFont, GriBrush, new Point(1030, 490));


                        graphics.DrawString(sertifikaId.PadLeft(12, '0'), new Font(ff, 16, FontStyle.Italic), GriBrush, new Point(1030, 915));
                        graphics.DrawString(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "/" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(), new Font(ff, 16, FontStyle.Italic), GriBrush, new Point(1030, 980));
                        graphics.DrawString(SertifikaOlusturan, new Font(ff, 16, FontStyle.Italic), GriBrush, new Point(1030, 1045));

                        graphics.DrawImage(qrCodeImage, 220, 1800, 400, 400);

                        graphics.DrawString("Sertifika Doğrulama", new Font(ff, 12, FontStyle.Regular), GriBrush, new Point(220, 1700));
                    }
                }

                PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
                SelectPdf.GlobalProperties.LicenseKey = "iaK4qbu8uKm9vr6puLCnuam6uKe4u6ewsLCw";
                doc.CompressionLevel = PdfCompressionLevel.NoCompression;
                PdfPage page = doc.AddPage(PdfCustomPageSize.A4, new PdfMargins(0f), PdfPageOrientation.Landscape);
                PdfRenderingResult result;
                PdfImageElement img1 = new PdfImageElement(0, 0, doc.Pages[0].ClientRectangle.Width, doc.Pages[0].ClientRectangle.Height, imgBackground);
                result = page.Add(img1);
                PdfPage page2 = doc.AddPage(PdfCustomPageSize.A4, new PdfMargins(1f), PdfPageOrientation.Landscape);
                PdfImageElement img3 = new PdfImageElement(0, 0, doc.Pages[1].ClientRectangle.Width, doc.Pages[1].ClientRectangle.Height, imgBackground2);
                result = page2.Add(img3);

                doc.Save($"{Core.Constants.FileResources.GetStudentCertificateDirectory()}\\{dosyaadi}");
                doc.Close();

                // SERTİFİKA OLUŞTUR

                // DB'YE YAZ
                var addedStudentCertificate = new StudentCertificate
                {
                    StudentID = request.StudentID,
                    CertificateID = request.CertificateID,
                    IssueDate = System.DateTime.Now,
                    Issuer = this.userService.GetName(),
                    IssuserId = this.userService.GetNameIdentifier(),
                    File = $"{Core.Constants.FileResources.GetStudentCertificateDirectory()}\\{dosyaadi}",
                    CreateByUserID = this.userService.GetNameIdentifier(),
                    CreateDateTime = System.DateTime.Now,
                };

                this.studentCertificateRepository.Add(addedStudentCertificate);
                await this.studentCertificateRepository.SaveChangesAsync();

                // DB'YE YAZ
                return new SuccessResult(Messages.CertificateGiven);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new ErrorResult(e.Message);
            }
```

Comment: It means the server doesn't have enough memory to store the PDF. Now, how do you fix this? Without knowing how you're creating the PDF, we'll never be able to help, all we can do is give vague tips like using streams

Comment: We can't guess what's going on without any code. Either the server doesn't have enough memory or the code is inefficient and creates so many temporary objects and memory fragmentation that it's no longer possible to find a big enough memory block to allocate. The second case is far more likely

Comment: For example, many .NET collections like `List<T>` use an array underneath to store their data. When that buffer is full, a new one is allocated with double the size and the old data are copied over. The old buffer gets garbage-collected eventually, but until that point it still takes memory. If you try to add 1M items to a List<T> one by one, you end up with 18 temporary buffers along with the final one, taking almost twice as much memory. You can avoid this by specifying the `capacity` argument when creating an array

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for your answers. I've included the code I used to generate the pdf in the post.